# T-SQL Crosstab count query

Tags: sql, pivot-table, crosstab, charindex

If have the following dataset:

[image]

... and I want to do a crosstab of sorts, counting the data against specific criteria e.g.:

**Colour criteria**: String contains "Blue", "Red", "Yellow" or "Green" (not case sensitive)

**Type criteria**: String contains "Car", "Lorry", or "Bus (not case sensitive)

... and I would like the result to look like the following:

[image]

Is there an SQL query that I can run on the original data to produce the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) with conditional aggregation; `CROSS APPLY` simplifies the generation of the list of colours:

```
select c.colour,
  sum(case when v.VehicleData like '%Car%' then 1 else 0 end) Car,
  sum(case when v.VehicleData like '%Lorry%' then 1 else 0 end) Lorry,
  sum(case when v.VehicleData like '%Bus%' then 1 else 0 end) Bus
from vehicles v
cross apply (values ('Blue'), ('Red'), ('Yellow'), ('Green')
) AS c(colour)
where v.VehicleData like '%' + c.colour + '%'
group by c.colour
```

Output:

```
colour  Car Lorry   Bus
Blue    3   1       0
Red     1   2       0
Yellow  0   1       1
Green   0   0       2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f30cc9f0c793a5c3f6a1c75fda36ca53)

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select c.colour,
  count(case when t.VehicleData like '%Car%' then 1 end) Car,
  count(case when t.VehicleData like '%Lorry%' then 1 end) Lorry,
  count(case when t.VehicleData like '%Bus%' then 1 end) Bus
from (
  select 'Blue' colour union all 
  select 'Red' union all
  select 'Yellow' union all
  select 'Green'
) c left join tbl1 t
on t.VehicleData like '%' + c.colour + '%'
group by c.colour
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68e4ccb5bc02a24266311c22fe47ecb2).
Results:

```
> colour | Car | Lorry | Bus
> :----- | --: | ----: | --:
> Blue   |   3 |     1 |   0
> Red    |   1 |     2 |   0
> Yellow |   0 |     1 |   1
> Green  |   0 |     0 |   2
```